# How to get a Let’s Encrypt wildcard certificate via cert-manager in Azure without changing DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, azure, lets-encrypt, wildcard-subdomain, nginx-ingress

How to get a Let’s Encrypt wildcard certificate for (an already working subdomain in) Azure?

I get https://cert-manager.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started-aks-letsencrypt/ running

But it uses only the sub-domain www and in part 2 the Azure cluster is changed for DNS confirmation - and not Nginx confirmation - I want the latter